# How can I get the transaction version from a hex dump?

Tags: transactions

I am currently looking into the structure of bitcoin transactions. As an example, I took the hex dump of [this transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/30713d08afa548d3465e380d6e1837354b29a1b6707e2a913b27776cf305fda4?format=hex):

```
010000000001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff5403df550a1b4d696e656420627920416e74506f6f6c373138fd004702c13ba070fabe6d6d6d9986fd3aedb9f8b00fab3c74c2e1d399fd0e6bc1d964aa57a08f78ac2d648002000000000000001eb50000c1377c00ffffffff04653c3a2a000000001976a91411dbe48cc6b617f9c6adaf4d9ed5f625b1c7cb5988ac0000000000000000266a24aa21a9ede0721e21cc17367eb4fcccf94c7e6ebc54757a693515f809307d4d6a31e0c8500000000000000000266a24b9e11b6d6eab9aaf2ccdc3cb05fb15989c512b84c8ef5f498559cd4d66e6104de8f9cdb100000000000000002b6a2952534b424c4f434b3a93320d7a461a95b953bd18e40aa031b5470d6258ccd82011999a5b290031529c0120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Looking at the [JSON format](https://blockchain.info/tx/30713d08afa548d3465e380d6e1837354b29a1b6707e2a913b27776cf305fda4?format=json), the transaction version should be `1`.

I've read that the first 4 bytes of a transaction encode the version number ([source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction)).

2 hex characters are one byte, so 4 bytes are 8 hex characters. So the version is `01000000`. But that would be `16777216`, not `1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Transaction_Verification we learn :

> Almost all integers are encoded in little endian. Only IP or port number are encoded big endian.

You should look at the https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness and flip the order of the bitstring to have the bit at the correct position

Using an online hex converter like this one
https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/ you can actually see that the hex interpreted as `uint32` results to `1`

[image]

Comment: You gave me the information that I need to change the order of the chars in the hexstring from "01234567" to "67452301". That was very helpful. Thank you 